# Classic asp: Error '800a01ad' ActiveX component can't create object

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, com

Getting **'800a01ad'  ActiveX component can't create object** while running a Classic ASP application on 64 bit windows 7. I have tried all suggested solution but no luck

1. I have enabled 32-bit on my IIS Application Pool.
2. I have registered the .DLL using C:/windows/syswow64/regsvr32.exe -- the registration is successful.
3. I have verified that the .DLL is found in the registry using C:/windows/syswow64/regedit
4. I have created a COM+Application server application and added my Dll, when i select the DLL it loads all its components in the Components Found Box but Listed "No" under Installed heading even after adding this dll.
5. Permission granted to IIS_USR on Dll directory.

Kindly Advice

Comment: 6. Grant IIS AppPool permission to dll direcotory

Comment: Granted, but still same error. DLL is copied in wwwroot/dll directory.

Comment: Check "Component services" in Control Panel. If your COM present there, check launch and activation permission

Comment: This may just give you a slightly different error message, but try `Server.Createobject` instead of `Createobject`

Comment: Do you get the same error if you create a .vbs file on the desktop and call some vbs code to create the object?

Comment: Thanks everyone for you response, we are finally able to resolve it by installing all dependencies.

Comment: @saira, how did you work out that all dependencies were not installed?

Answer (score 2):

**Running Classic ASP on IIS 7.x - 8.x Checklist:**

1. Under Server Manager, go to "Manage" and "Add Roles".
   Look for Web Server (IIS) --> Application Development --> check ASP and Server Side Includes.
   Add IIS 6 Management Compatibility.
2. Do not name site folders with .com, .net, etc at the end.
3. Create NEW user account:

   - [app pool user identity] is user: app_pool_blahblahblah, pw: xxxxxx
4. In Application Pool, advanced settings:

   - set .Net Framework version to "v2.0" <-- fixed issue with default asp doc not working!
   - set "Enable 32-bit applications" to TRUE.
   - under Process Model, change Identity to "[app pool user identity]" account we created above.
   - This is default: be sure "load user profile" is set to FALSE.
   - This is default: be sure "maximum worker processes" is "1".
5. In Server Manager under features add SMTP server.
   Install IIS6 Resource Kit so you can use Metabase Explorer.
   Grant the [app pool user identity] user read access to the /Local Machine/SmtpSvc/  in the IIS Metabase Mail: In IIS 6 Management Console:
   http://intellitect.com/configuring-windows-smtp-server-on-windows-2008-for-relay/

   - Under SMTP Virtual Server Properties:

     1. "Access" Tab --> Relay: add IPs of this server, including 127.0.0.1
        -- "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "fully qualified domain name" put name of server
     2. "Delivery" Tab --> Advanced: for "smart host", for Godaddy, put "dedrelay.secureserver.net"
     3. "Delivery" Tab --> Outbound connections: Make sure limits are set to 100.
     4. "Security" Tab --> add "[app pool user identity]" and IIS_IUSRS
6. In IIS 7 and 8 under web site:

   - Under ASP:

     1. under limits change max req entity and buffering limit to 1024000000
     2. set script language to "vbscript"
     3. set "send errors to browser" to true
     4. set "Enable Parent Paths" to true
     5. ONLY IF PROBLEM: set enable buffering to "false"
   - Authentication --> edit "Anonymous Authentication" and set to app pool identity.
   - under Management (at bottom) go into "Configuration Editor".

     1. In the dropdown go to System.web --> http runtime and change maxRequestLength to 1024000000
     2. In the dropdown go to System.webserver/security/requestFiltering --> chg allowDoubleEscaping=true
     3. In the dropdown go to System.webserver/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication --> chg userName to blank.
   - ONLY IF PROBLEM: under error pages: under 404 set to "/home.asp" and "execute URL"
   - ONLY IF PROBLEM: edit c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config: change  to "Allow"
7. Set "Modify" Permissions for [app pool user identity] for the following folders:

   - your web site
   - windows\temp
   - inetpub\temp
   - inetpub\mailroot
   - ONLY IF PROBLEM: windows\serviceprofiles\networkservice\AppData\Local\Temp?
     AND Set Permissions in registry:
   - ONLY IF PROBLEM: HKeyLocalMachine\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines?
     FOR THESE USER ACCOUNTS:
   - IIS_IUSRS
   - [app pool user identity]
   - NETWORK SERVICE
8. For your FTP site, go to FTP Authorization Rules and add a rule to allow your specific user(s) or group(s).
9. Install and Use Process Monitor to find permissions issues - filter
10. Make sure SSL v2 and v3 are not being used:

    - Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
    - In Registry Editor, locate the following registry key/folder:
      HKey_Local_Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders
      \SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0
    - Right-click on the SSL 2.0 folder and select New and then click Key. Name the new folder Server.
    - Inside the Server folder, click the Edit menu, select New, and click DWORD (32-bit) Value.
    - Enter Enabled as the name and hit Enter.
    - Ensure that it shows 0x00000000 (0) under the Data column (it should by default). If it doesn't, right-click and select Modify and enter 0 as the Value data.
    - Do the same with SSL 3.0.
    - Restart the computer.
    - Verify that no SSL 2.0 or 3.0 ciphers are available at ServerSniff.net or the Public SSL Server Database.
11. SSL issue where Safari tells client that it needs a certificate.

    - Go into IIS settings for the SSL-protected site.
    - Click on "SSL Settings"
    - Choose "ignore".

Comment: A lot of that list is pointless. You've just listed a load of settings that you can change in IIS that fix certain issues and in some cases cause more harm then good.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will get that error if you are using:

```
Set objConfig=CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")
```

when instead you should be using:

```
Set objNewMail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
```