# migrate COM Visible .NET assembly to another server

Tags: .net, dll, asp-classic

I am trying to migrate a COM visible .NET assembly to a new server. There is a classic ASP application running on the current server which uses this DLL to create object call the methods. Now I am tasked to migrate the application to a new server and I am stuck at this DLL migration. Problem is the team who created the DLL and registered in current server is no longer with us.

I have copied the DLL, ran the command `regasm /tlb /codebase "full path of the dll"` 
When I ran the application, the object is not created.
I verified the keys in registry, tried both 32bit and 64bit regasm tools to register, checked under References->COM in Visual Studio..etc.

Now I have no clue what else to check and if I missed any crucial step in migration of the DLL.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: This duplicate should help, there's a checklist you can go through to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have gone through the checklist. Some of them I have actually done. However, further searching brought me to this question which actually is my error. I was missing the IIS_USRS permission on the dll folder. Once I gave the permission !!bam!! it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27615726/classic-asp-error-800a01ad-activex-component-cant-create-object/41840648

Comment: I have upvoted your checklist answer and the question in above link

Comment: I’m glad you found it useful @Ravi